# Rotating the cantor ternary set

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the points on the number line belonging to the cantor's ternary set.Let each point be rotated  a full circle.What important properties about the 2D object so obtained we can know?Like what is its measure(area)? etc.if it has it been considered already in the literature,I would be highly obliged for any links/references.

Comment: Perhaps anticlimactically, the new set will still have zero area and uncountable cardinality, no matter how we rotate it; however this is certainly an interesting idea.

Comment: This set is named _Cantor target_ in this [article](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-Cantor-target-the-set-swept-out-by-rotating-the-middle-third-Cantor-set-about-an_fig7_339948402).

Comment: Integrating the characteristic function of the rotated set using polar coordinate should yiled $0$.

Comment: I assumed that you were rotating  about $(\frac  1  2,0)$ in my previous comment.